# Return sum with modulus GROUP BY

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need a sum of results of a query Group by a field. I explain this with an example.

This is the results of find()

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5749a5fd7aed9ced75b94218"), "groupValue" : "5", "weight" : 123 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5749a5fd7aed9ced75b94219"), "groupValue" : "5", "weight" : 345 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5749a5fd7aed9ced75b9421a"), "groupValue" : "2", "weight" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5749a5fd7aed9ced75b9421b"), "groupValue" : "2", "weight" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5749a5fd7aed9ced75b9421c"), "groupValue" : "5", "weight" : 567 }
```

Now I want a results where the sum is calculated for all the weight of a groupValue.

For this example I want

```
(123 + 345 + 567)mod(5)
and
(1+2)mod(2)
```

**SOLUTION FINDED:**
I solved it with my own solution.
I registered a new javascript function:

```
db.system.js.save(
{
_id : "getModulus" ,
value : function (x, modulus){ return x % modulus; }
}
);
```

Now load it:
`db.loadServerScripts();`

Now i create two function: map, reduce.

```
var map = function () {
var key = {groupValue: this.groupValue};
emit(key, {weight: this.weight, groupValue: this.groupValue});
};

var reduce = function (key, values) {
var sum = 0;
var groupValue = 0;
values.forEach( function (value) {
sum += value['weight'];
groupValue = value['groupValue'];
});
var number = getModulus(sum, groupValue);
return {weight: number};
};
```

and now call my mapReduce:

```
db.hits.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: {inline:1}})
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Do you want only the sum? what is `5` in `mod(5)`

Comment: Given two numbers, a (the dividend) and n (the divisor), a modulo n (abbreviated as a mod n) is the remainder from the division of a by n. For instance, the expression "7 mod 5" would evaluate to 2 because 7 divided by 5 leaves a remainder of 2, while "10 mod 5" would evaluate to 0 because the division of 10 by 5 leaves a remainder of 0.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Is `5` and `2` the "groupValue" field value?

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
    db.getCollection('collectionName').aggregate( [ 
{ $group : { _id : "$groupValue" ,total:{$sum:"$weight"}} },
{ $project : { _id:0,groupValue : "$_id" , total : "$total" ,
    remainder: { $mod: [ "$total", "$_id" ] } } }] )
```

its working fine and one more thing please change groupValue field `(String to Number)` then only it will work